# Does the cactus wren use a call to elicit insect prey movement and detection?

Tags: entomology, ornithology, hearing, predation

I will be referring primarily to a 2013 paper, [If a bird flies in the forest, does an insect hear it?](http://rsbl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/9/5/20130319), and my own investigation. Bird flight sound frequencies overlap with the hearing range of most tympanate insects. There are several insects that possess hearing for which the function is not known and it is hypothesized that this capacity is used to avoid predation. For example, silent butterflies and grasshoppers have broadband audio sensitivity and some calling insects appear to have hearing tuned outside of the call frequency.

I have observed cactus wrens (*Campylorhynchus brunneicapillus*) foraging for insects on the ground outside my window (southwest desert, USA) and have noted that they invariably emit a characteristic odd periodic call while they are so engaged. You can hear my recording of one such hunting wren made April 18, 2017 here. [Cactus wren foraging call](https://youtu.be/nfr8XmP8u64)

I used the open source audio processing application, [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/), to analyze the wren call I recorded. Here is a spectrogram of the call:
[image: 6.73 Hz period of 1940 Hz burst].

You will note that the call is periodic at about 7 Hz. For comparison, typical pulsed bird wing sounds (the sound of bird wings as they are hovering or approaching prey) are around 18 Hz frequency. Those wing sounds are broadband bursts though, approximately 49 kHz +/- 18 kHz. I mention this because the cited paper and many others looking at bird sounds and insect hearing have explored primarily the hypothesis that it is the flight sound the insects are detecting. My own idea is that some bird species actually generate sounds within such a range in order to provoke prey insects into fleeing from hiding or a stationary position.

Typical moth and butterfly audio frequency response is given here:
[image]
(reproduced from the work cited earlier).

The cactus wren call may be seen to exhibit energy in the 1.6kHz - 2.20kHz range primarily, peaking at 1954 Hz (spectrographic analysis of exactly that portion not shown). This seems interesting given that Cyphoderris crickets call at 12 kHz, but their ears are most sensitive to 2 kHz (almost exactly the wren burst frequency peak).

I could not find research examining my hypothesis and thought I would ask the question here, i.e., is there research examining the possibility that certain bird species use calls to enhance detection of prey insects (and the related question, does this seem likely given what others may know about the subject of insect hearing, its range and uses, bird predation behavior, etc.)?